# Getting Mario-Mask Koopas in “Super Mario World”

Tags: super-mario-world

I’ve read about Koopas wearing Mario-masks in *Super Mario World*, and the pictures below look familiar (though I can’t recall if it’s because I got them in the game or saw them on the Internet).

I can’t find any direct information on how to get them other than *“finishing the special world”* or *“completing 100% of the game”*.

Does anyone know exactly what is required of the player to get the masked Koopas and when/where they show up?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I always liked how sitting on the SPECIAL screen for about 5 or 10 minutes changes the music :P

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a secret warp in the Star Road. Upon entering it, you will end up in the [Special World](http://www.mariowiki.com/Special_World). If you complete all 8 of the Special World levels, a new Star Road appears with a warp that leads back to Yoshi's House. If you enter it, some drastic changes occur in [Dinosaur Land](http://www.mariowiki.com/Dinosaur_Land):

- World backgrounds change (to a Fall-like instead of a Spring-like colour scheme).
- Koopas transform into Mask Koopas.
- Piranha Plants will change into Pumpkin Plants.
- Jumping Piranha Plants will turn into Jumping Pumpkin Plants.
- Bullet Bills are replaced with Pidgits.
- Goombas turn into a yellowish color and have sunglasses. (GBA version only)
- Pokeys turn into sawblade-like creatures. (GBA version only)

(Source: [Super Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_World#Changes_After_Special_Level_Completion))

These changes occur in the entire world, and are permanent.

[image] [image]

Comment: I know about the special world, I’ve already played through it. I’m trying to find out exactly what is needed. Does it happen automatically after beating the eighth level in there? Is it like a flag that causes all Koopas in the game to wear masks from that point on? Do they appear only in the special world or back in the normal map too? Do they stop showing up if you do something (like load a game, play through a level, etc.)? etc.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. I'll put more information in my answer.

Comment: It might be helpful to also point out that Koopa change colors in addition to becoming mask Koopas. Blue Koopas in particular become a lot more common.

Answer (score 6):

After beating the final Star Road level, "Funky", a second star-road teleporter will appear to the left of the level. Taking this teleporter will send you all the way back to Yoshi's home back in world 1, and will simultaneously activate the "Special World".

Here's a picture to explain how to avoid triggering the Special World:
[image]

Comment: Ahh, I should probably specify that the warp is actually what triggers the change.

Answer (score 0):

After defeating Funky (not entering the warp, as other answers say - I even checked it, to be sure - the warp is not special in any way (other than that it's one-way)) in Super Mario World, or getting 96 exits in Super Mario Advance 2, the following changes occur. Once the given event, the changes cannot be reversed (ignoring cheating, arbitrary execution glitch and stuff like that).

- Overworld palettes change (aside of Special World).
- [Galoombas](http://www.mariowiki.com/Galoomba) will be yellow and wear sunglasses (SMA2 only).
- All Koopa (Para)Troopas become (Para) Mask Troopas.
- Jumping Piranha Plants become Jumping Pumpkin Plants
- Bullet Bills become Pidgit Bills. In SMW only, there is a quirk that causes the diagonal and vertical Bullet Bills of Vanilla Dome 4 not to change.
- Pokeys' segments turn into small saws (SMA2 only).
- All Green Mask Koopas and their shells become Yellow, with exception for Para Mask Troopas.
- All Red Mask Koopas and their shells become Blue, with exception for Para Mask Troopas.
- Intro and title screen show new enemies (SMA2 only).